# Use v-if for a specific element in a v-for

Tags: javascript, vue.js, javascript-framework, v-for

So I have the following HTML on my Vue page

```
    <div v-for="profile in lab.profiles" v-if="edit || profile.active" class="lab-tests-row-div" @mouseover="">
        <div class="clickBox" :class="['clickBox-' + lab.id + '-' + profile.id]" @click="openInfoPopup"></div>
        <p class="lab-tests-row test-info-row" v-bind:class="{'active': profile.active}">
            <span v-bind:class="{'opacity50':!profile.active}">{{profile.name}}</span> 
            <i v-if="edit" class="fa fa-minus pull-right removeTestIcon" aria-hidden="true" @click="toggleProfile(lab.id, profile.id)"></i>
            <span class="pull-right" v-bind:class="{'opacity50':!profile.active}">{{profile.code}}</span>
        </p>
    </div>
```

I want to show the element 'clickBox' when the user hovers over that row, if I use a v-if with a boolean and change it on mouseover they will all show since they are in a v-for, how I only show the div in the row they are hovering over?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the [v-for](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-for) directive you can get the index of the element `v-for="(profile, index)`

Use that index to only show the style you want it, in your template.

for example.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    selected : 0
  }
})
```

```css
.selectedClass {
  background: lightblue
}

.hoverClass:hover {
  background: lightcoral
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<main id="app">
  <div v-for="(elem, index) in 4">
    <p class="hoverClass" :class="{'selectedClass': selected === index}" @click="selected = index" >{{elem}}</p>
  </div>
</main>
https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54025706/edit#
```

**Edited**

It's perfeclty fine combine `class="..."` with the Vue binding `:class="..."`

**Edited 2**

For nested `v-for` declare another name for index.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app'
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<main id="app">
    <div v-for="(item, i) in 2">
       <div v-for="(elem, j) in 3">
        v-for item {{ i }} v-for elem {{ j }}
       </div>
    </div>
</main>
```

Comment: The problem with this solution is the v-for is nested inside another v-for so all the other elements with the same index in the other v-fors will also show.

Comment: Example here: https://codesandbox.io/s/vjn655zyx7
selected is 0, but the first item is displayed in both sublists instead of just one as I want